# DAX Enterprise Portal == Sharepoint Portal

Tags: axapta

Just wondering if DAX EP is same as SP.
In other words if we have experience in using Sharepoint do we need to take separate training
for DAX EP. Can anyone please confirm.
Thanks,
N

Comment: If you find an answer useful then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

[AX Enterprise Portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa855178.aspx) is a [SharePoint application](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-building-sharepoint-applications-HA010239046.aspx) that access data through the [AX Application Object Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa623946.aspx).

Conclusion: EP != SharePoint

I cannot guess whether you need training based on that information.